# Salvar hora do cadastro no banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um formulário e sempre que alguem registrar, preciso salvar a hora do cadastro na minha tabela Historico2 dentro da propriedade `DateTime? Quando`.

```
    public partial class Historico2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Quem { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Quando { get; set; }

    public decimal Peso { get; set; }

    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public decimal? TOTAL { get; set; }
}
```

Como posso passar o valor `DateTime.Now()` sempre que alguém registrar para a propriedade `DateTime? Quando`?

A ActionResult Create() do meu controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Quem,Quando,Peso,Valor,TOTAL")] Historico2 historico2)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Historico2.Add(historico2);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(historico2);
    }
```

Comment: Use `Triggers` em sua aplicação e pare de se preocupar com as datas em sua lógica de negócio:

[https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Triggers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Triggers)
[https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Armindo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado o cenário a forma mais fácil de resolver o problema é fornecer a data antes de adicionar o registro ao contexto, como no exemplo abaixo. Mas existem outras alternativas como configurar a esse valor como padrão no próprio banco de dados ou como no pattern de repositório onde você faria isso no seu metódo de `"salvar()"`. Existem várias formas de atender esse requisito.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Quem,Quando,Peso,Valor,TOTAL")] Historico2 historico2)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        historico2.Quando = DateTime.Now;            

        db.Historico2.Add(historico2);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(historico2);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Leandro! Entendi o conceito